# Automapper related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I have my `Quotation` model containing a property of type `Customer`. I want to populate the `Customer` property using automapper when I fetch the quotation from context with the following code:

```
var quotation = context.Quotation.Include("Customer").Single(q => q.Id == 1);
var quotationDetailsViewModel = mapper.Map<QuotationDetailsViewModel>(quotation);
```

Currently, my `quotation.Customer` is populated, but it is not mapping to corresponding fields in `quotationDetailsViewModel`. I know I will have to give some mapping, but don't understand where and how to do that.

Here are my model & viewmodel classes:

```
public class Quotation
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public long CustomerId {get; set;}
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
    public string Status {get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
}

public class QuotationDetailsViewModel
{
    public long QuotationId {get; set;}
    public long CustomerId {get; set;}
    public string Status {get; set;} //This is quotation status
    public string Name {get; set;} //This is customer name
}
```

Here is my automapper MappingProfile.cs

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<QuotationDetailsViewModel, Quotation>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<QuotationDetailsViewModel, Customer>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I am using .net mvc core 2.2 with `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` version 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to map relational entity

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqeId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; } // relational entity
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
}


public class CommentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqeId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my profile

```
public class CommentProfile : Profile
{
    public CommentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is your related entity? Like I have `Customer` inside `Quotation`. Sorry, I don't understand your example could you please elablorate. I tried adding `MemberList.None` in my `MappingProfile` but it doesn't help.

Comment: My related entity is Post. So you need to add related entity to your DTO object

Comment: Ok, but in my `QuotationDetailsViewModel`, I have flattened the properties of `Customer` to avoid having unnecessary properties which I don't need in my view. So I guess I cannot take your approach.